# Why am I getting an error from MLPutFunction after getting the MathLink from LibraryLink?

Tags: librarylink

Based on the example on the documentation page for 
`processMathLink`, I've got the following C++ code:

```
void MathematicaFunctionDescriptor::Register(WolframLibraryData lib_data) const
{
    MLINK link = lib_data->getMathLink(lib_data);
    Checked(&MLPutFunction, link, "EvalutatePacket", 1, "MLPutFunction(EvaluatePacket, 1) failed");
    Checked(&MLPutFunction, link, "Set", 2, "MLPutFunction(Set, 2) failed");
    Checked(&MLPutSymbol, link, maFunctionName.c_str(), "MLPutSymbol(" + maFunctionName + ") failed");
    Checked(&MLPutFunction, link, "LibraryFunctionLoad", 4, "MLPutFunction(LibraryFunctionLoad, 4) failed");
    Checked(&MLPutString, link, "MaCALFrontEnd", "MLPutString(\"MaCALFrontEnd\") failed");
    Checked(&MLPutString, link, mgFunctionName.c_str(), "MLPutString(\"" + mgFunctionName + "\") failed");
    PutSymbolList(link, input);
    Checked(MLPutSymbol, link, output.c_str(), "MLPutSymbol(" + output + ") failed");
    int errorCode = lib_data->processMathLink(link);
    if (errorCode != 0)
        throw GMathematica::CallBackError(errorCode, "Cannot register function " + maFunctionName);
    int nextPacket = MLNextPacket(link);
    if (nextPacket == RETURNPKT)
        MLNewPacket(link);
}
```

This is called from a function `initializeAll` which catches
all exceptions, and converts them into error returns to
Mathematica.  `Checked` is a simple template function which
wraps a call to its first arguement, checking its return status,
and throwing an exception with its last argument as a message if
the call fails.

I've invoked this from Mathematica by:

```
LibraryFunctionLoad[ "MaCAL", "initializeAll", {}, Integer ]
%[]
```

The `LibraryFunctionLoad` seems to work; the dll "MaCAL"
contains the function "initializeAll", which loads all of the
necessary DLLs (about 20) in the correct order, then invokes the
wrapper for the above function in the DLL "MaCALFrontEnd".
I get back the error message `"MLPutFunction(EvaluatePacket, 1)
failed"`.  Regretfully, I don't know how to find out why it
failed.

More generally: I'm trying to execute "LibraryFunctionLoad" for
all of my functions, from the C++ code invoked by the first
function.  (I actually tried this first in
`WolframLibrary_initialize`; I moved it to a separate function
when this failed, but with no noticeable difference.)  Is it
possible to do this from `WolframLibrary_initialize`?  And is
this the correct technique, or is there a better solution?

And more generally, is there some good literature, on the net or
in the form of a book, which explains how to do these sort of
things.  The Wolfram documentation is some of the worst I've
encountered—they seem to confuse quantity with quality.